# Backup of Job's List only

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, backup, sql-server-agent

Goal:
Reuse the SQL server agent jobs list.

Problem:
The list contains a lot of jobs and I need to reuse the jobs list in a another time without recreating it.

Based on the example of the picture, can I get the sourcecode of every job and enable reusing it when I establish a new database from scratch?

I would prefer not to recreate the job list from scratch.

Information:
*The list contains a lot of jobs.

[image]

Comment: What *exactly* are you looking to get out of the "job list"? Job name? What about job steps? Job owner? Operator notification? Next scheduled run? Execution history?

Comment: Everything what is containing in every job and its title. One example is a database model, you use SQL code to create a database model and you can reuse the code to recreate the model. Exactly the same thinking for jobs. Please tell me if you need more information.

Comment: To restate, I think you're looking to script out every detail about the jobs. Is your answer going to look like a series of data dumps or is is going to look like stored procedure calls to recreate the jobs, job steps, schedules etc?

Comment: Q.1"I think you're looking to script out every detail about the jobs." A. yes it is. ------------- Q.2" is is going to look like stored procedure calls to recreate the jobs, job steps, schedules etc"    A. yes it is.

Answer (score 1):

I've built a command-line utility that creates a .sql script file containing T-SQL that will recreate all SQL Server Agent Jobs for the specified SQL Server instance.

The utility takes several command-line parameters, as below, which necessitates running it from the command prompt, `cmd.exe`.

```
MVCTSQLJobScripter.exe /server:localhost /outfile:C:\temp\AgentJobs.sql
```

Be aware that this tool comes with no warranties, and is use at-your-own-risk.  I have used it on my own SQL Servers, and it works for me.

The utility uses the [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Agent.Job.Script](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.agent.job.script.aspx) method to output T-SQL, so the output should be precisely what is needed to recreate jobs.

You can download the binary and prerequisites from http://blog.mvct.com/technology/tool-for-scripting-sql-server-agent-jobs/

There are also many commercially available products that provide various features to move or copy jobs from server to server, such as the [Idera SQL Admin Toolset](http://www.idera.com/productssolutions/sqlserver/sqladmintoolset).  I neither work for, nor am I associated with Idera in any way.